# Meaning of 纸 in radicals

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, radicals

I was asked this in my Chinese class and have to write a mini paragraph on it:

> 解释一下“纸”这个字部首是什么？最早纸是什么意思？

I know that the first part of 纸 means 丝绸, but what does the second part of the character mean? Also, I don't exactly get what 最早纸是什么意思 is asking for...

Comment: 纸 is 形声字. The second part 氏 stands for its 'sound'. There are couple of links might help if you baidu. here is one of them: http://www.xiuwenyuan.com/ziyuan/e7bab8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

氏(Shì) is the phonetic component in 纸(Zhǐ), which is a '[phono-semantic compound character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification)'

> Phono-semantic compound characters
>
> 形聲 xíng shēng "form and sound" or 諧聲 xié shēng "sound agreement"
>
> These are often called radical-phonetic characters. They form the majority of Chinese characters by far—over 90%, and were created by combining two components:
>
> 1. a phonetic component, also called "rebus", Japanese 音符 (onpu), that is, a character with approximately the correct pronunciation.
> 2. a semantic component, also called a determinative, one of a limited number of determinative characters which supplied an element of meaning (in most cases this is also the radical under which a character is listed in a dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

According to the question, you should only need to describe the radical (found in this case as the left hand component) **糸**, not **氏**.

The word **部首** is literally translated as *section header*, and strictly refers to the header under which the character is grouped in dictionaries. Each character has only **one** 部首, just like each English word has only **one** *first letter* under which they are found in dictionaries.

If your teacher also asks you to describe 氏, then that should be done in a separate question; if they think that 氏 is a 部首 in the character **紙**, then they are unequivocally wrong. 紙 is a semantophonetic (**形聲**) compound character under the traditional [*liushu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification) scheme of classifying characters. You can only refer to 氏 as a **聲部** (*sound component*) in 紙, not a 部首.

**最早"紙"是什麽意思** (punctuation added) is asking you to find out what 紙 meant in its first appearance in historical literature. This may be trying to get you to appreciate that many characters have changed meaning over the course of history.